# Assigning variable column names for a variable data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, assign

I'm looping through a list of data frames, `dfList`, all of which are Nx2, where I want to change the column names for each data frame to `c("Date",  dfList[i])`. For example:

```
dfList <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")

for(i in 1:length(dfList)){
   names(get(dfList[i])) <- c("Date", dfList[i])
}
```

This results in the error:

> Error in names(get(dfList[i])) <- c("Date", dfList[i]) : 
>     could not find function "get<-"

`names(get(dfList[i]))` itself works, and returns the original column names. Also, `c("Date", dfList[i])` works.

Any idea how I can work-around the error I'm receiving?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for(i in 1:length(dfList)){
    temp <- get(dfList[i])
    names(temp) <- c("Date", dfList[i])
    assign(dfList[i],temp)
}
```

It should be noted that you should generally avoid `get` and `assign`, and it's probably better to assign the column names when you create the data frames.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok using purrr:

```
library(purrr)

df_list <- list(data.frame(1:10, ncol = 2), 
                data.frame(1:20, ncol = 2),
                data.frame(1:30, ncol = 2))


map2(df_list, 1:length(df_list), function(x, y) setNames(x, c("Date",  paste('df', y, sep = ""))))
```